# change ng-class based on click

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I want to change the class of an element when the user clicks on another element.

first of i have this span:

```
<span class="yesterdaysValue">{{category.content.Value}}</span>
```

second of i have an img attribute which gets its class based on a function declared in the controller(which works fine)

```
<img ng-class="{true: getArrowClass(category.content.Value, category.content.ValueOneWeekAgo)}[true]" ng-src="{{getArrowSrc(category.content.Value, category.content.ValueOneWeekAgo) }}" />
```

what I want is when i click the text within the span, i want to change the class of the img attribute. I would like to use my getArrowClass if possible, but I have no idea how to do this.

```
$scope.getArrowClass = function (value, valueOneWeekAgo) {
        return value >= valueOneWeekAgo ? 'greenArrow' : 'redArrow'
    }
```

Comment: Can you create fiddle?

Comment: change the class to what?

Comment: to whatever, it really doesnt matter. I just want to change the class of the img attribute completley. In the end im gonna send in two values, if value1 > value it returns greenArrow , otherwise it returns redArrow ( just like in my $scope.getArrowClass

Comment: @steffokeffo like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/67tpf542/2/ ?

Comment: im not sure. I want to call the getArrowClass from when i click the span and from there send in two values that i have.

Comment: ok, i can describe it better:
When i click the span, i want to call a function ,lets say called ChangeArrowClass(value1,value2) . What this function does is change the class of the <img> attribute.

Comment: @steffokeffo My answer should solve this for you, did you try it ?

Comment: @OmriAharon could you show me with this example? jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/67tpf542/2

Comment: @steffokeffo There's no need, just add `ng-click="click = !click"` to your span like I wrote in my answer and it will work.

Comment: i tried, but its still not working.

Comment: @steffokeffo The function is getting called, the question is does it return a different value ? You can place a `console.log("in function")` inside your `getArrowClass` function and see in the console that it prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since all you need is to make angular do another digest, you can just place an `ng-click` in your span that basically does nothing (or, almost nothing) but it's enough to trigger a digest and therefore recalculate the class for your image:

```
<span class="yesterdaysValue" ng-click="click = !click">span</span>
```

I made a generic fiddle that shows the purpose. (in my `someFunc` method in there it just returns a variable on the scope, in your case it will do the actual method).

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s83n8cn6/1/)